# What is the preferred unit testing tool for C development in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, unit-testing

What is the preferred unit testing tool for C development in Visual Studio?

Comment: Are you programming in C++ or C#?

Comment: There's the built-in Microsoft unit testing framework and I also know know of NUnit. We use NUint because we already know how to call NUnit tests from our NANT build scripts. If you will be doing automated builds and want to run the test at build time, then consider editing your question to ask if a particular unit testing framework is easier to integrate with the build automation tool of your choice.

Comment: If the OP writes "C" I'd assume C. Not C++ or C#, but C.

Comment: I'm programming in C.  I think NUnit is just for .net...correct?

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search reveals a few unit testing tools for C:

[Check](http://check.sourceforge.net/)
[CUnit](http://cunit.sourceforge.net/)

I doubt they are designed to work with Visual Studio specifically, although I'm certain you'd be able to use these tools anyways as Visual Studio has good support for 3rd party tools.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/)... It provides project files for Visual Studio

And you can use [Google Mock framework](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/)

Comment: Can cou write pure C (not C++) tests with Google Test?

Comment: Not really, test files must be compiled as C++. But if you want to test pure C code you can do it from Google Test Framework

Answer (score 0):

[CUnit](http://cunit.sourceforge.net/) is supposed to be good, but I have not used it myself...